# Как обрезать по нужным координатам?

Tags: изображения, gd, php

Приветствую всех!

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, не могу понять, как реализовать данное действие.

Мой скрипт - обрабатывает изображение, находит нужную облать вокруг нее по средствам **`imagerectangle`** рисует красный прямоугольник. В этот же момент мне нужно взять область внутри данного прямоугольника и вытащить её в новое изображение и сохранить.

Не понимаю вот каких вещей: все функции для обрезки и копирования прямоугольных объектов созданы так, что нужно: знать ширину-высоту прямогульника (а она у меня всегда разная зависит от объекта). Ладно ширину я ещё понимаю, как узнать, и координаты верхнего левого угла (x,y) есть и координаты нижнего правого (x,y), но везде не нужен нижний правый, а нужен верхний левый, ширина и высота, которую я не понимаю как узнать имея: ширину, верхний угол (x,y), нижний правый угол (x,y). Вот решил попросить помощи, может загадка таится под носом, но non-stop марофон без сна дает знать о себе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высота = разности ваших двух координат по оси Y

Comment: Не получается что-то